# Aliens hiding important information about the human race; story ends “‘You don’t’ he said?”

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

And thereby makes clear in 4 words what the whole story was about.  In a 60's or 70's era anthology I think.  I’ve always remembered it as being an example of good or clever writing.  I've never read another story with the same effect. If I gave any more clues it would spoil the story. I only read it once yet I can still remember it… but what was the story?

EDIT:
The aliens were hiding some important information on the human race and the hero spent the whole story trying to find out what it was.

Comment: The ability to format your question with spoiler tags will prevent those from not wanting to know more, from learning it. However, without more information, this question may prove very difficult to answer. Placing >! before text will prevent seeing it without holding your mouse over it

Comment: Lets see - if it gets no answers I guess I'll have to add some spoilers.  But I'd like to think that if someone had read it they would remember it as I have.

Comment: Intentionally hiding information won't make it easier for people to help you. [Spoiler tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72877/whats-the-exact-syntax-for-spoiler-markup) will allow you to post that info without ruining the plot. As it stands, I'm on the verge of voting to close for being "unclear".

Comment: It's debatable if spoiler tags are really needed for a 50+ year old story.

Comment: @Richard - I could be misunderstanding, but I think the idea was that the four words were *"'you don't', he said."*

Comment: @Hypnosifl - I just spotted that.

Comment: I can't remember anything about this story except the line before the last line, in which the alien is asked (more or less): 'What could you have told the human race that's more important than that we have souls?'... and the reply is: 'You don't' ... I think the author was one of the big names of the early '60s, though the story may be later - Poul Anderson? Gordon R Dickson? possibly one of the Dangerous Visions stories (but it's very late and I'd need to fetch the stepladder to reach that shelf...)

Comment: Since it seems that OP is being *deliberately obscure*, I've voted to close. Witholding known information about the story (even with the best of intentions) is not appropriate behaviour.

Comment: Not an answer but a really great trilogy that plays with some of the same concepts is the Nights Dawn trilogy.  It was the first thing that came to my mind when reading the spoiler for this.

Comment: The Nights Dawn trilogy is the opposite of a short story though !

Comment: Who are the ^H^H^H^H^H^H people voting to close the question as "unclear what you're asking"? Question has 14 upvotes, **answered within half an hour**, answer (accepted) has 22 upvotes, and the question is **unclear??** What is **unclear** about the last 4 words being "'You don't' he said"? That is one of the clearest and most precise story identification questions I've ever seen.

Comment: @user14111 - I voted to close for the reason listed above. In a misguided attempt to preserve the twist, he was **deliberately obscure**, making it harder to locate the story and wasting the time of other users. That you solved it is testament to your skill, not the quality of the question.

Comment: @Richard Is that really a reason to close ? I thought that would be a reason to downvote, because "unclear what you're asking" is not really the case as I see it.. The question is straight forward. Don't worry, no offense, I'm just wondering, what's the reason to specifically close for "unclear" ? He provided all infos to tell us **exactly** which story he means (context + the exact last 4 words, which seem to be the core of the story). I doubt there's a story where these specific infos would also fully apply. It's not hard to tell exactly what he's asking I think..

Comment: @dagon313 - As I said, it's not "unclear" but, by design, it's certainly less clear than it could have been.

Comment: @Richard Fair enough :) But: to me that seems like we **either** need a new category in reasons to close (OP not helping or whatever) **or** simply downvote. It seems exaggerated to close it.. Looking at the definition of the "unclear" section, this certainly does **not** fit the description. It is quite clear what he's asking and there's no other answer that would fit his question to the full extent.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

["The Martyr"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58305), a novelette by [Poul Anderson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poul_Anderson); first published in [*The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, March 1960](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61252), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v018n03_1960-03_PDF/Fantasy__Science_Fiction_v018n03_1960-03_PDF#page/n3/mode/2up).

> He turned to the watching Cibarrans and shouted, "That's what you've been trying so hard to keep us from finding out, that death isn't the end! But why? You claim to be interested in our happiness. You couldn't have told us anything more wonderful than that we have immortal souls!" The stranger vanished. Elth remained a second more. Narden realized it was a surrender: the answer given now because it would be discovered anyway, unless these humans joined in hiding the fact. When he spoke, it was with surgical compassion. **"You don't," he said.**

Comment: Thats so good, I wish I hadden't spoiled it

Comment: M. Night Shyamalan approves of this story.

Comment: Now all I need is an explanation. Read the story, but the ending isn't terribly clear.

Comment: @user31178 : (rot13) Vzzbegny fbhyf qb rkvfg. Gur Pvoneenaf unir gurz. Uhznaf qba'g. Jr jbhyq qrfcnve vs jr sbhaq bhg, fb guvf vf jul gur Pvoneenaf gel gb uvqr vg, whfg yvxr cneragf abg gryyvat puvyqera gung Fnagn Pynhf vfa'g erny.