# Trying to find two short sci-fi stories

Tags: short-stories, books, aliens, hard-sci-fi, anthology-book

1. A man, some sort of functionary arrives to a planet. The planet is I habited by aliens that are literally incomprehensible.
   He talks to some of the scientists that try to establish contact, then, against their advice goes to meet those aliens himself.
   He experiences a major trip-like experience that almost destroys his mind, but gets better.
   The scientists then say that they are trying to expose the child to the aliens communications, to get him to bridge the gap, and it is revealed that maybe aliens are trying to do the same.
2. A group of military scientists has kidnapped a bunch of aliens, to try to get them to reveal the secret of the psi phenomena.
   They experiment on those aliens, until one of those aliens dies, and in dying he manages to use his psi powers to summon help.
   That allows the scientist to figure out that psi-phenomena imply an existence of the immortal soul... which then remaining aliens reveal that humans do not have.

Both were in some sort of old sci-fi anthologies, but I can't recall either authors or names of the stories.
Please help!

Ps: I think maybe first story was called "ambassador" or something similar, and one of the protagonists of the second had name that started with L.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You really need to split this into two questions so that the stories can be identified separately.

Comment: The second story is "The Martyr" by Poul Anderson; see this old Q&A: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79591/aliens-hiding-important-information-about-the-human-race-story-ends-you-don-t

Comment: What 'child' in the first question?