# Story which ends with humans not being capable of riding the standing wave that binds the members of the higher alien race together

Tags: story-identification

Looking for a story where humans encounter a new alien race and at the end of the story find that humans are not capable of riding the standing wave that binds the members of the higher race together.

Comment: Was this a _short_ story? In roughly which year did you read it? What sort of world/time period was the story set in? And can you elaborate on what you mean by _"riding the standing wave"_?

Answer (score 7):

["The Martyr"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58305), a novelette by [Poul Anderson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poul_Anderson) which was also the answer to the old question [Aliens hiding important information about the human race; story ends "'You don't' he said?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79591/aliens-hiding-important-information-about-the-human-race-story-ends-you-don-t); first published in [*The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, March 1960](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61252+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v018n03_1960-03_PDF/page/n3/mode/2up). You may have read it in one of [these compilations](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?58305).

**The space aliens have great "psionic" powers; they ride "the standing wave of the universe":**

> "Well, if you insist. Considering that space is of finite extent, however large, and that psi transmission is by waves, however unlike classical electromagnetics . . . it should theoretically be possible to establish a, uh, **a standing wave
> on a cosmic scale.** In effect, a vast total amount of psionic energy would pervade all space in an orderly pattern. Its source would be the basic psionic radiation of all life, everywhere in the cosmos. An adept could draw as much of this energy as he needed — and could handle — at any one time, and use it. Dying organisms would always be putting more back, so the total would remain nearly constant. In fact, it would increase, because
> radiated energy isn't lost with the death of the radiator, and new life is always getting born. This adds a rather fantastic clause to the second law of thermodynamics. Physical energy becomes more and more unavailable, as entropy increases, but psionic energy becomes more and more available. Almost as if the universe were slowly evolving from an inanimate, purely physical state, to an ultimate . . . well . . . pure spirit."

**Earthlings would like to do that too:**

> Elth leaned forward. "But see here," he argued, "how do you
> know psionics would be of any value to you? Do you envy the
> Osirian his ability to breathe hydrogen, or the Vegan his immunity to ultraviolet radiation?"
>
> "Those aren't lacks which handicap us," Narden snapped. "We can send a remote-control robot anywhere one of those races can go. But how can we even know what we *are* until — "
>
> The idea flashed through him, wildest of chance shots, but he
> hurried on without daring to stop:
>
> **" — our minds have also ridden the standing wave around the universe?"**

**But they can't:**

> He turned to the watching Cibarrans and shouted, "That's
> what you've been trying so hard to keep us from finding out, that death isn't the end! But why? You claim to be interested in our happiness. **You couldn't have told us anything more wonderful than that we have immortal souls!"**
>
> The stranger vanished. Elth remained a second more. Narden
> realized it was a surrender: the answer given now because it
> would be discovered anyway, unless these humans joined in hiding the fact. When he spoke, it was with surgical compassion.
>
> **"You don't," he said.**

Comment: What the F.. we don’t. 

Comment: @FreeMan Thanks for pointing that out. It was an OCR error in the text version at the Internet Archive that I copy-pasted from. I fixed some of those but my weak eyes missed that one.

Comment: That's the story I was looking for - thanks.

Comment: @Mr.S You're welcome! You can "accept" my answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.