short story in which humans capture superior aliens in order to study them
Short story, possibly from 60s, 70s or even 80s.
There is a galactic community of aliens. Alephs are at the apex with what appears to be telepathy and teleportation that may be innate or from biotechnology. Daleths rank low, and humans are somewhere in the middle.
Some humans use Daleths to capture a party of Alephs; they use Daleths because the Daleths are insufficiently evolved for the Alephs to easily read their minds and intentions. The humans use some form of broacast interference to inhibit the escape of the Alephs by teleportation.
The humans wish to study the Alephs in order to discover how their abilities work. One human receives an urgent phone call to say that one Aleph is strangling another but arrives too late to intercede. Shortly afterwards, a rescue party of Alephs arrive wearing helmets to protect against the inhibition field.
As they leave one of the rescue party talks with a human. The human deduces that the dead Aleph traveled somehow to tell of the capture and asks the Aleph "why didn't you tell us that a part of us survives death?". The Aleph replies (sadly?) "you don't!"

"The Martyr" by Poul Anderson, as described here? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79591/aliens-hiding-important-information-about-the-human-race-story-ends-you-don-t

It is definitely The Martyr. The aliens are the Cibarrans. One of the aliens is called Elth and another Alanai, so maybe that has been misremembered as Daleth and Aleph.

Haydon, please let us know if this is the book so we can mark this as a duplicate.

Definitely this story. I'm mildly surprised by the author, I don't associate Poul Anderson with this type of story.
